# Issues with rounding the monthly payment to the hundredths place

Tags: python

I have just began learning python, switching from a java background and I am having trouble understanding why my numbers wont round under monthlyPayment.

```
loan = input("Please enter the loan amount.\n")
loan = int(loan)
interest = input("Please enter the interest rate.\n")
interest = int(interest)
years = input("Please enter the number of years desired.\n")
years = int(years)
i = interest/1200
monthlyPayment = (i/(1-(1+i)**(-12*years))*loan)
monthlyPayment = round(int(monthlyPayment),2)
print("With a loan of " + str(loan) + "$, an interest rate of " + 
str(interest) + "%, and after " + str(years) + " years the monthly payment 
totals at " + str(monthlyPayment) + "$.")
```

Any help understanding where my error occurred would be appreciated!

Comment: `int(monthlyPayment)` converts your number to an integer. How do you expect to round an integer number?

Comment: You want a `float` not an `int`

Comment: `monthlyPayment =int(round(monthlyPayment/100.0,2)*100)` I believe you want monthly payments to the nearest 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the `int` function to convert your variable to an integer you remove any decimal point present. It is useless to round an integer.

e.g.

```
int(10.33344443)
>> 10
```

If you remove the `int` the variable remains a `float` with a decimal point precent so your script will act as you expect it to.

e.g.

```
round(10.33344443,2)
>> 10.33
```

Comment: Thanks! I completely overlooked this!